# How to get aleph and beth symbols in similar font?

Tags: fonts, symbols, hebrew

If aleph, beth, gimel, and daleth are needed in their mathematical meanings (identifiers for cardinality), how can we get them in the same font or at least reasonably similar in style. The following simple approach makes aleph different from the rest in style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

The aleph is smaller and has thinner strokes:

[image]

Apparently the reason is that amssymb does not have aleph. What might be the simplest fix?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are other font that can be used:

- **MnSymbol:**

  [image: MnSymbol]
- **FdSymbol:**

  [image: FdSymbol]
- **TX fonts:**

  [image: TX]
- **PX fonts:**

  [image: PX]
- **cjhebrew:**

  [image: cjhebrew]

OpenType fonts (LuaTeX/XeTeX):

- **Latin Modern Math:**

  [image: Latin Modern Math]
- **Asana Math:**

  [image: Asana Math]
- **XITS Math:**

  [image: XITS Math]
- **TeX Gyre Pagella Math:**

  [image: TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
- **TeX Gyre Termes Math:**

  [image: TeX Gyre Termes Math]
- **Linux Libertine:**

  [image: Linux Libertine]
- **GNU FreeFont/FreeSerif:**

  [image: FreeSerif]
- **GNU FreeFont/FreeSans:**

  [image: FreeSans]

---

### MnSymbol

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{MnSymbol}

% Definitions without package "MnSymbol", which also changes
% other math symbols.
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{MnSymbol}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{MnSyC}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
      <-6>  MnSymbolC5
     <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
     <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
     <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
     <9-10> MnSymbolC9
    <10-12> MnSymbolC10
    <12->   MnSymbolC12}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
      <-6>  MnSymbolC-Bold5
     <6-7>  MnSymbolC-Bold6
     <7-8>  MnSymbolC-Bold7
     <8-9>  MnSymbolC-Bold8
     <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\aleph}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{"AF}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\beth}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{"B0}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\gimel}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{"B1}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\daleth}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{"B2}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: MnSymbol]

### FdSymbol

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{fdsymbol}

% Definitions without package "fdsymbol", which also changes
% other math symbols.
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{fdsymbol}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \newcommand{\fdsy@scale}{1.0}
  \newcommand\fdsy@mweight@normal{Book}
  \newcommand\fdsy@mweight@small{Book}
  \newcommand\fdsy@bweight@normal{Medium}
  \newcommand\fdsy@bweight@small{Medium}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{U}{FdSymbolA}{b}{n}%
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
      <-7.1> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@mweight@small
      <7.1-> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@mweight@normal
  }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{b}{n}{
      <-7.1> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@bweight@small
      <7.1-> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@bweight@normal
  }{}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\aleph}{\mathord}{fdsymbols}{"C7}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\beth}{\mathord}{fdsymbols}{"C8}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\gimel}{\mathord}{fdsymbols}{"C9}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\daleth}{\mathord}{fdsymbols}{"CA}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: FdSymbol]

### TX fonts

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{txfonts}

% Definitions without package "txfonts", which also changes
% other math symbols.
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{txfonts}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{txsymbols}{}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{txAMSb}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{txsymbols}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{txsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{txAMSb}{U}{txsyb}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{txAMSb}{bold}{U}{txsyb}{bx}{n}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txsyb}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\aleph}{\mathord}{txsymbols}{64}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\beth}{\mathord}{txAMSb}{105}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\gimel}{\mathord}{txAMSb}{106}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\daleth}{\mathord}{txAMSb}{107}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: TX]

### PX fonts

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{pxfonts}

% Definitions without package "pxfonts", which also changes
% other math symbols.
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{pxfonts}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{pxsymbols}{}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{pxAMSb}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{pxsymbols}{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{pxsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{pxsy}{bx}{n}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{pxAMSb}{U}{pxsyb}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{pxAMSb}{bold}{U}{pxsyb}{bx}{n}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{pxsyb}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\aleph}{\mathord}{pxsymbols}{64}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\beth}{\mathord}{pxAMSb}{105}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\gimel}{\mathord}{pxAMSb}{106}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\daleth}{\mathord}{pxAMSb}{107}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: PX]

### cjhebrew

See egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170498/16967).

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{cjhebrew}

% Definitions without package "cjhebrew"
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{cjhebrew}\@tempswafalse\@tempswatrue
\if@tempswa
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{cjheb}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{cjheb}{m}{n}{%
    <-11> s*[1.2] cjhblsm
    <11-> s*[1.2] cjhbltx
  }{}
  \newcommand{\cjhebfamily}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{cjheb}\selectfont}
  \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcjheb}{\cjhebfamily}
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{amstext}
\newcommand*{\mathhebrew}[1]{\text{\cjhebfamily#1}}
\def\aleph{\mathhebrew{\symbol{'047}}}
\def\beth{\mathhebrew{\symbol{'142}}}
\def\gimel{\mathhebrew{\symbol{'147}}}
\def\daleth{\mathhebrew{\symbol{'144}}}

\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: cjhebrew]

### Latin Modern Math (LuaTeX/XeTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Latin Modern Math]

### Asana Math (LuaTeX/XeTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Asana Math]

### XITS Math (LuaTeX/XeTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: XITS Math]

### TeX Gyre Pagella Math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: TeX Gyre Pagella Math]

### TeX Gyre Termes Math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: TeX Gyre Termes Math]

### Linux Libertine

See Herbert's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170497/16967).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range={\aleph,\beth,\gimel,\daleth}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Linux Libertine]

### GNU FreeFont/FreeSerif

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range={\aleph,\beth,\gimel,\daleth}]{FreeSerif.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: FreeSerif]

### GNU FreeFont/FreeSans

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range={\aleph,\beth,\gimel,\daleth}]{FreeSans.otf}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: FreeSans]

Comment: You, sir, seem to have too much time on your hand ;) Very nice answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you find a Hebrew font, you can use it; in this example I use the fonts provided by the `cjhebrew` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from cjhebrew.sty (with scaling added)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cjheb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cjheb}{m}{n}{%
  <-11> s*[1.2] cjhblsm
  <11-> s*[1.2] cjhbltx
}{}
\newcommand{\cjhebfamily}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{cjheb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcjheb}{\cjhebfamily}

% provide the commands in case amssymb is not loaded
\providecommand{\beth}{}
\providecommand{\gimel}{}
\providecommand{\daleth}{}
% renew the commands
\newcommand{\mathhebrew}[1]{\text{\cjhebfamily#1}}
\renewcommand{\aleph}{\mathhebrew{\char'047}}
\renewcommand{\beth}{\mathhebrew{\char'142}}
\renewcommand{\gimel}{\mathhebrew{\char'147}}
\renewcommand{\daleth}{\mathhebrew{\char'144}}


\begin{document}
$X\aleph \beth \gimel \daleth Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could scale it (1.5x horizontal, 1.1x vertical).

EDITED to work in all math styles (thanks, tohecz), and provided a slight vertical shift and kern for better matching.  Lastly, enclosed in a group, so that it works directly in a subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\oldaleph\aleph
\def\aleph{{\ThisStyle{\scalebox{1.5}[1.1]{%
  \raisebox{-.2\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\oldaleph$}}\kern-.2pt}}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\[ \scriptstyle \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth \]
\[X_{\aleph_\aleph}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Preferably `\let\oldaleph\aleph \def\aleph{...}` (naming consitency). As well, `\aleph` appears often in indices, therefore `\mathpalette` should be used here IMHO. Still, +1 for the idea, it looks reasonably consistent, I like this font much more than MnSymbol one, not speaking about the ugly sans-serif variants, which just look badly in serif maths.

Comment: @tohecz  Thanks for the suggestion.  I haven't mastered "The Mysteries of \mathpalette", so I just used my `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax to accomplish it.

Comment: For latin modern math, can we invoke aleph, beth, gimel, daleth only?

Comment: @M.Logic I am no expert on that font, but it can be downloaded (here, for example, http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html) and then you can search it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

run it with `xelatex`. `unicode-math` allows to use single characters from another font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont[range={\beth,\gimel,\daleth,\aleph}]{Linux Libertine O}   
\begin{document}
\Huge
בגדא
$ \aleph \beth \gimel \daleth $
\end{document}
```

[image]