# \beth not recognized in my Latex?

Tags: hebrew

I can't get my installation of latex to use `\beth` without using the amssymb package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\aleph\alpha\beta$
%$\beth$
\end{document}
```

This compiles. If I remove the `%` from the penultimate line, it doesn't know what that command is.

However, various sources seem to imply that `\beth` is a valid latex math command, such as https://wikieducator.org/Help:LaTeX_Symbol_Tables_-_Mathematics . None of them make mention of needing amssymb, and indeed, they list it right after `\aleph' which does not require the package.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170476/how-to-get-aleph-and-beth-symbols-in-similar-font

Comment: You need `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: While adding the amssymb package does fix the error, my question is more of a "why". `\aleph` works without that package. Every reference I can find on `\beth` implies it should too, but it doesn't for some reason on my installation. Does my MWE work on your installation (IE, the problem is my installation) or does it also fail (IE, the problem is that all the places that document this are wrong)?

Comment: Page 45 of the LaTeX User Guide (L. Lamport) provides `\aleph`, but not `\beth`, that is why.

Comment: My guess is that the main reason for why `\aleph` is included in virtually all "basic" sets of TeX and LaTeX math symbols, whereas `\beth`, `\gimel` etc are not, is an historical accident, *viz.*, Cantor's use of `\aleph` in`$\aleph_0$` etc. This usage more or less guaranteed that there would be a relative high typographic need for `\aleph`, both before and after the advent of computer-based typesetting. If Cantor or any other widely-cited mathematician had used `\beth`, `\gimel` etc with any kind of frequency, these symbols would probably be included in the "basic" symbol sets as well...

Comment: the reason `\aleph` is included among the basic symbols is that knuth required it for "the art of computer programming".  presumably the need for `\beth` and other hebrew letters was not there through at least the first three volumes of that series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, there are easy-to-access references for which symbols are defined where, especially if you know the command name. Typing

```
texdoc comprehensive
```

at a command prompt will give you the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List. Searching it for `\beth` will show you that this character is part of the AMS Hebrew font, the MnSymbol font, the fdsymbol font, the `boisik` Hebrew letters, Stix Hebrew letters, and so forth.

It also gives you a link to the `amsfonts` package page, so you know what to include.  It also mentions that `\aleph` is a basic LaTeX command, by linking to a table of LaTeX2e math symbols.