# How to invoke aleph, beth, gimel and daleth only in the latin modern math font?

Tags: xetex, symbols, luatex, unicode, hebrew

First a MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}


\begin{document}
$\aleph,\beth,\gimel,\daleth$ 
\end{document}
```

Compile it with XeLaTex, we have

[image]

The last three symbols are clearly different from ones in the `amssymb` package. This is come from [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170494/140814). But I don't want to use `unicode-math` and not want to use other symbols form latin modern math. So is there any way to invoke aleph, beth, gimel and daleth symbols only and not to invoke other letters or symbols in the latin modern math font? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Is loading the `amssymb` package permitted? Please also clarify what you mean by "invoke". Do you maybe mean, "load a (font) package"?

Comment: @Mico It's better not to call `amssymb`. But `amssymb` could be also permitted.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I would argue that it's not easy to try to do serious math typesetting without the `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages...

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want here, latin modern doesn't have beth gimel or daleth, like computer modern it only has aleph.

Comment: @David Carlisle I update the statements.

Comment: oh so you are using xelatex or lualatex not pdflatex (that certainly was not clear before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want something like the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\lmotf{latinmodern-math.otf}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathlmotf}{TU}{latinmodern-math.otf(0)}{m}{n}

\def\aleph{\mathlmotf{^^^^2135}}
\def\beth{\mathlmotf{^^^^2136}}
\def\gimel{\mathlmotf{^^^^2137}}
\def\daleth{\mathlmotf{^^^^2138}}


\begin{document}

$\aleph,\beth,\gimel,\daleth$ 
\end{document}
```

Which makes

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: @M.Logic mathspec loads fontspec so you are already using fontspec